# Assign associated products and attributes to configurable products via soap v2 api

Tags: configurable-product, associate-products, soap-api-v2

I have created the simple and configurable products by soap v2 api. 
But I can't able to assign the associated products and attributes to the configurable products. I tried the below code,

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 
$session = $proxy->login('******', '********'); 

$attributeSets = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeSetList($session);
$attributeSet = current($attributeSets);
    $productData = array(
                'name'=>'Configurable Product',
                'description'=>'Configurable Product',
                'short_description'=>'Configurable Product',
                'website_ids'=>array('base'),
                'categories'=>array(2),
                'status'=>1,
                'visibility'=>4,
                'tax_class_id'=>0,
                'weight'=>0,
                'stock_data'=>array(
                    'qty'=>10000,
                    'is_in_stock'=>1,
                ),
                'associated_skus' => array('V - Neck'),
                'additional_attributes' => array(
                    'single_data' => array(
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'color',
                            'value' => 5,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'price'=>10,
        );
        $proxy->catalogProductCreate($session,'configurable',$attributeSet->set_id,'Configurable Product 23',$productData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a 3rd party module to allow for such functionality unfortunately.

- https://github.com/jreinke/magento-improve-api
- http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/